# quit function call before mainloop in tkinter multiprocessed script

Tags: python, events, opencv, tkinter

The script below **opens a video file** and **displays it in a tkinter label**. The frame acquisition is made in another process.

My problem is that my `quit_()` function will succeed in closing the full script when calling it after a video was loaded (the python interpreter is then idle), but **destroys the root window and leaves the program running** if I try to quit before loading a video (the python interpreter is then pending, and I have to kill it manually). The `loadswitch`variable is a **tkinter BooleanVar** that detects the loading of a video, and causes the script to wait for its value to change before entering the main loop.

It appears to me that the problem would be that the fact of not having a filepath as argument causes some kind of exception in `image_capture()` resulting in the quit problem. However, no exception is raised on script execution.

Any idea as to how I would get the full script to terminate on `quit_()` before video loading would be greatly appreciated!

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pipe
from Queue import Empty
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog

#tkinter GUI functions----------------------------------------------------------
def quit_(root, process):
   if tkMessageBox.askokcancel(message='Are you sure you want to quit?', icon='question', title='Quit'):
      process.terminate()
      root.destroy()

def load_win(root, loadswitch, con):
   #create child window when 'load video' button is clicked
   win = tk.Toplevel()
   win.resizable(False, False)
   #displays message, radiobuttons to choose data type, and gets the absolute file path if file
   tk.Label(win, text='Please choose video data type:').grid(column=0, row=0)
   videotype = tk.StringVar()
   videostream = tk.Radiobutton(win, text='Video live stream', variable=videotype, value='videostream').grid(column=0, row=1)
   videofile = tk.Radiobutton(win, text='Video file', variable=videotype, value='videofile').grid(column=0, row=2)
   def load_video(root, win, videotype):
      if videotype.get()=='videostream':
         win.destroy()
         #loadswitch.set(True)   #line to activate when stream capture code implemented
      elif videotype.get()=='videofile':
         filepath = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
         win.destroy()
         if filepath:
            loadswitch.set(True)
            con.send(filepath)
         else:
            pass
   tk.Button(win, text='OK', command=lambda: load_video(root, win, videotype)).grid(column=0, row=3)
   root.wait_window(win)

def update_image(image_label, queue, waitframe,root,process):
   if queue.get()==None:
      quit_(root,process)
   else:
      frame = queue.get()
      im = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
      a = Image.fromarray(im)
      b = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=a)
      image_label.configure(image=b)
      image_label._image_cache = b  # avoid garbage collection
      root.update()
      time.sleep(waitframe)

def update_all(root, image_label, queue,waitframe,process):
   update_image(image_label, queue, waitframe,root,process)
   root.after(0, func=lambda: update_all(root, image_label, queue,waitframe,process))

#multiprocessing image processing functions-------------------------------------
def image_capture(queue,con):
   videopath = con.recv()
   vidFile = cv2.VideoCapture(videopath)#pour mettre la web cam, changer pour 0 et commenter les ligne passant fps et waitframe
   fps = vidFile.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
   waitframe = 1/fps
   con.send(waitframe)#sending waitkey duration through pipe to update_image()
   while True:
      try:
         flag, frame=vidFile.read()
         if flag==0:
            queue.put(None)
            break
         else:
            #image processing code goes here
            queue.put(frame)
            cv2.waitKey(10)
      except:
         continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
#initialize multiprocessing
queue = Queue()
pcon, ccon = Pipe()
#start video procesing
p = Process(target=image_capture, args=(queue,ccon))
p.start()
#GUI of root window (les menus arretent la video, car ils occupent le processus...)
root = tk.Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.iconify)
root.title('FlowMap 0.1')
root.resizable(False, False)
image_label = tk.Label(master=root)# label for the video frame
image_label.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=1)
#fill label with image until video is loaded
bg_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
image_label['image'] = bg_im
# quit button
quit_button = tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit',command=lambda: quit_(root,p))
quit_button.grid(column=1, row=1)
#load video button and a switch to wait for the videopath to be chosen
loadswitch = tk.BooleanVar(master=root, value=False, name='loadswitch')
load_button = tk.Button(master=root, text='Load video',command=lambda: load_win(root, loadswitch, pcon))
load_button.grid(column=0, row=1)
#print an 'about' window
tkMessageBox.showinfo(message="FlowMap 0.1, (c) Raoul SCHORER 2013")
#wait for input to begin processing
root.wait_variable(loadswitch)
waitframe = pcon.recv()
print 'waitframe is: '+ str(waitframe)
# setup the update callback
root.after(0, func=lambda: update_all(root, image_label, queue, waitframe,p))
#exit program
root.mainloop()
print 'mainloop exit'
p.terminate()
print 'image capture process exit'
```